# Declaring functions and variables multiple times in C++

Tags: c++, declaration, definition, one-definition-rule

In C++, declaring a variable multiple times shows an error during compilation. For example:

```
int x;
int x;
```

While declaring a function multiple times doesn't show any error during compilation. For example:

```
int add(int, int);
int add(int, int);
```

Why is this distinction in C++?

Comment: Function can be overloaded but the number and types of parameters should be different. Variables can not be overloaded.

Comment: Its not overloading its just redeclaring . declaration can be done any time.

Comment: that's not declaration of function, it is declaration of prototype, that can be done multiple times. This is distinction since C actually. Prototype is declaration without body, declaration AND body considered a definition, that can occur only once

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note that `int x;` is not (just) [declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations), it's [definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition). So error arisen since [ODR](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule) is violated, i.e. only one definition is allowed in one translation unit.

A declaration of variable could be written as:

```
// a declaration with an extern storage class specifier and without an initializer
extern int x;
extern int x;
```

In the meantime `int add(int, int);` is a declaration (of function) exactly. Multiple declarations in one translation unit are fine, ODR is not violated.

Comment: You might want to continue and explain that the declaration `int add(int int)` is not a definition, so ODR does not apply.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It answers my doubt. :)

Comment: It's worth noting that forward declaration of functions in headers is extremely important for dependency management (essentially saying "you can assume that at link-time there should be a function with this signature"). This forward declaration can easily lead to duplicates if different headers with the same declaration are ever included. However, duplicate definition of variables means 2 different instances of something with the same name, and no way to disambiguate them. (Hence it's not allowed.)

Comment: What about declaring a variable inside a loop?

Comment: @YouKnowWho The rule is same, you can't define variable multiple times with same name in the same scope.